# '09/11/2023' changes '20/11/0009' in Oracle

Tags: timestamp, to-date, to-char

Day is getting assigned as year with 00 as suffix and Century's first two digits are getting assigned as date when date is getting assigned to different field.

I want the date to be in same format when it gets assigned somewhere.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This probably happens because there are discrepancies between your date formats in different columns. Use to_char() to format the date with the desired format:
https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/TO_CHAR-datetime.html#GUID-0C3EEFD1-AE3D-452D-BF23-2FC95664E78F